# ASP.Net Core Web Application(.Net Framework) issues EF Code First approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a ASP.Net Web Application(.Net Framework) with MVC template and installed EF 6 latest stable build. Created a model and Context classes.

```
public class IAMContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Put below code in Controller Index method before it returns an view

```
using (var db = new BasicTemplates.Models.IAMContext())
        {
            db.Blogs.Add(new BasicTemplates.Models.Blog{ Name = "Another   `   Blog " });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

lastly connection string in Web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="IAMContext"
connectionString="Data Source=***\SQL2016;Initial Catalog=IAM;Integrated Security=true;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This works fine, creates a table called Blog in the IAM DB. When I try to do same thing in ASP.Net Core Web Application(.Net Framework) Web API project, it is not working. Here I have provided the Connection string in appsettings.json. Rest of the code is same.

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "IAMContext": "Server=192.168.0.3\\SQL2016;Database=IAM;Trusted_Connection=True;"
 }
```

After executing it is throws an error which says

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Thanks

Comment: It can't find the database at that address. Try replacing the datasource in the web.config with the server in address in appsettings and see if you get the same error.

Comment: did you try giving `Integrated Security=true` in connection string or specific username and password?

Comment: Did not work for both providing database address and setting Integrated Security=true also.

Answer (score 0):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
 "IAMContext":     "Server=192.168.0.3\\SQL2016;Database=IAM;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

It looks like permission issue.Try giving username and password in connection string like

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"IAMContext": "Server=192.168.0.3\\SQL2016;Database=IAM;
User=youruser; pass=yourpass; Trusted_Connection=False;"
```

BTW is 192.168.0.3 is your local machine?
To check if its not a permission issue, open SSMS and try connect to your db giving the exact config that you used in your connectionstring.

Comment: It is not a permission issue, I am able to connect to db by giving the IP Address of it as well as with its name in SSMS. It did not work by providing username, password and setting trusted_connection to False. Still same error exists.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search I came to know that, ASP.Net Core projects will not support EF. They are supposed to use Entity Framework Core  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/index.

Comment: Here is a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6) about creating EF6 class lib for ASP.NET core project.